# Why can't call region.getId1() in didEnterRegion() to get beacon's first Id when the app runs in the background?

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I've read some posts asking how to get the beacon's id while the app runs in background, and [davidyoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461050/davidgyoung) suggests one can use the ranging API to get beacon's id.

Why can't we just call `region.getId1()` in `didEnterRegion()` to get the region's associated beacon's first id, since there are methods like `getId1()`, `getId2()` and `getId3()` in class Region.

I've try to call the methods above, and they all return `null`, do I misuse the these methods?

Comment: show your `didEnterRegion()` function code

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this.   But you must understand the difference between the `Region` and a `Beacon` class and how wildcards work in regions.**

When you use the ***monitoring*** APIs, you register a beacon `Region` that can have wildcards for any of the beacon's three identifiers.  When an identifier in the `Region` is set to null, that means it is a wildcard, and it will match any beacon it finds regardless of that identifier, so long as the other non-null identifiers in the `Region` match the beacon.

The monitoring APIs provide a call to `didEnterRegion(Region region)` whenever one or more beacons are first encountered that match the registered region.  The passed `Region` object is the same one that was registered when monitoring was started.  It will have null values for any wildcard identifiers.  If you are seeing null in the identifiers in this object, then it is probably because the code set up monitoring to start with wildcard identifiers.  The reference applications do this, creating a `Region` that has wildcards for all identifiers like this:

```
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
```

The above code will match any beacon, because all three identifiers are set to a wildcard value of null.  However, it is also possible to start monitoring like this:

```
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", Identifier.parse("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"), Identifier.parse("1"), Identifier.parse("1")));
```

The above code will only match a beacon with identifiers 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 1, and when the callback is made, you can read all the identifiers.

If you want to combine wildcards with reading the beacon identifiers, then you do need to use the ***ranging*** APIs.  Understand that when using wildcards, the monitoring APIs can't tell you which exact beacon caused you do enter the region, because many matching beacons could have been encountered at the same time.  The ranging APIs solve this problem by providing a list of every beacon seen.

Comment: yes, I vague the difference between **Region** and **Beacon**. I did create a Region that has wildcards for all identifiers. However  I need to known the exact beacon id and I also want my App to monitor beacon signal in the background, does it mean that I have to use **raning** APIs in my `Application` which implements `BootstrapNotifier`?

Comment: See the Ranging Sample Code here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html